# Can I change the WebKit CSS rules in my browser?

Tags: html, css, webkit

For the occasional late-night computing session, I like to tone done the colors of the sites I'm using for the sake of retaining my eyesight. My typical go-to extension is Stylish, a useful tool that loads custom CSS in webpages.

Curiosity and tampering led to the question I have here. Can I change WebKit's CSS defaults in WebKit's tags to better suit my needs? I'm speaking in regards to custom browser CSS rules, those used in Safari and Chrome for `-webkit-`, and others for other browsers. Is there any plain-text file that helps define these rules, which would allow me to edit them and therefore tamper with browser-loaded defaults?

Comment: Why are people downvoting and voting to move this to Super User? What makes it off topic here?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for are userstyles that would let you customize your browsing experience (if you're really specific about setting up your browser, you may want to do a quick google search on userscripts as well for more functional modifications)

The rules you are referring to are, for all purposes, bona-fide css rules with vendor prefixes.

Check out http://userstyles.org/ and from there you can download an add-on for Chrome here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend going on with this. Making a page appear differently in a certain browser,

- is not user friendly, but rather confusing
- and its sure to decrease usability.

Having said that, that are many webkit specific rules which you can define. And, overriding them is the **only way of changing the default behavior**.

[This](http://css-infos.net/properties/webkit) page consists all the webkit specific rules and you can override these rules by **redefining** them in your style sheet.

For example:

```
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
```

Override the default rule and orients the elements vertically.